# Why adding an unique ittem to my combo-box it takes too long to add it?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, netbeans-7.1

I have a weird problem with my combo box... (I use Netbeans 7.1 and Java code) when I add an item `cbxUnidad.addItem("TODOS");` it takes 1300 ms to add it, so when I open that form (on execution time) it takes more than 4 seconds to open it.
I know that that specific code takes that long because i have used this to know how much time takes that line:

```
long empieza  = 0;
long duracion = 0;
empieza  = System.currentTimeMillis();
cbxUnidad.addItem("TODOS");
duracion = (System.currentTimeMillis() - empieza);
System.out.pr
```

intln("Adding the item TODOS last " + duracion + " ms");

So in that way i get 1.3 seconds (1300 ms) when java execute that sentence... that's kinda weird and very slow... so i wanna know if anyone knows why or how to change the sentence.

Here i Leave the initCode for the combo-box:

```
cbxUnidad = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
cbxUnidad.setMaximumRowCount(25);
cbxUnidad.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
cbxUnidad.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        cbxUnidadItemStateChanged(evt);
        }
});
```

Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'r probably doing some other operations unless adding only one item to a combo doesn't take too much time (actually it doesn't make sense adding one item taking 1.3 seconds).
My advice is :

- Create another class having one *combobox* .
- Add item(s) to the combobox and see how much time it takes.

  ```
  long empieza  = 0;
  long duracion = 0;
  empieza  = System.currentTimeMillis();
  cbxUnidad.addItem("TODOS");
  duracion = (System.currentTimeMillis() - empieza);
  java.text.NumberFormat nf = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
  String totalTime = nf.format(totalTime/1000d);
  System.out.println("Adding the item TODOS last " + totalTime+ " seconds");
  ```

Comment: Yeah its weird, but that sentence takes 1.3 seconds... At the method I add that only item and then in a `for` sentence I add more items from a `list`, and that `for` takes about 2 ms, that's why I'm really confused because adding 1 element takes 1.3 sec and adding multiple items from a `for` takes 2 ms! that's really WEIRD.

Comment: I'm trying to add your code but I'm having some errors, it says that i cant make `java.text.NumberFormat nf = new java.text.NumberFormat("#0.00000");` because `NumberFormat` is abstract.

Comment: Ahh, Sorry about that it's `...NumberFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0.00000");`

Comment: thank you a lot, but, somehow using `cbxUnidad.addItem("TODOS");` lates 1300 ms and using `cbxUnidad.insertItemAt("TODOS", 0);` lates 2 ms... maybe it has to do something that my combo-box has a model? `cbxUnidad.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));` Do you know why? And don't worry, its ok that I add "TODOS" at the first positicion.